# Furigana options are gone

Tags: feature-request, furigana, site-health

I have noticed that for some time, the furigana options that used to be at the bottom of the page in the footer "navigation" are gone.  I hate seeing furigana by default, and prefer to hide them.  What do we need to do to get this menu option back?

---

Some banter in the chat between me and @snailplane:

> @istrasci Basically, I didn't make the meta post yet, and cypher isn't around so it hasn't been fixed. I don't know how to fix it myself (at least, not at the moment), so if one of us makes the meta post complaining about it, maybe SE will notice and fix it for us ;-)
>   Pretty sure they just changed the HTML for the footer, so the custom script is failing to add the furigana options.
>   So someone needs to figure out how to do that, but I've been pushing myself kind of hard working on something unrelated to the site so I haven't taken the time yet.

Comment: I don't think the tag "site-health" is applicable here - it's about whether a site has enough traffic to remain viable, or growing the size of the website. The former is no longer applicable, as we've graduated from beta, and the latter isn't relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for that - the footer markup changed and we didn't remember the Furigana script.

I've updated the script to work for the footer correctly (and the update that will go out sometime in the next few weeks - the one on Stack Overflow).

This should be coming your way in the next build.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update.

Comment: Is it gone again? Seems to be there in [rev 2018.3.9.29374 (2018-03-12)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312105844/https://japanese.stackexchange.com) but gone in [rev 2018.3.15.29453 (2018-03-15)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180315184421/https://japanese.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Pang - not much I can do about this these days, as I am no longer an employee (and haven't been for a year). I suggest opening a new bug or popping into The Tavern chat room on meta.se - and see if you can tag a developer or CM.